# Who first implemented the three-breasted character?

Tags: history-of

I am trying to figure out who implemented the first three-breasted character, as seen in *Total Recall* (1990).

I know someone who says there was such a character in the original *Battlestar Galactica* series but he has no proof to back up his claim.

Does anyone know anything about that, or of any other instances where it might have first happened?

Comment: See http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Multiboobage

Comment: she's got 3 tits? nice. (Quoting 'Paul')

Comment: It may have been as far back as the written word, since it seems to be [possible in reallife](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accessory_breast).

Comment: Incan mythology typically depicts multiple-breasted female goddesses. This is likely not the origin, but is older than the 1900s.

Comment: What is meant by "implemented" here? Or "happened"?

Answer (score 43):

The concept can certainly be dated as early as 1978, with the first mention of [Eccentrica Gallumbits, the triple-breasted whore of Eroticon Six](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minor_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_characters#Eccentrica_Gallumbits) in the *Hitch-Hiker's Guide to the Galaxy*.

Comment: There is [this book cover](http://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/f/f0/NHNDRDG19XX.jpg) from 1970. I don't recall that it illustrates anything in the book.

Answer (score 28):

[Aelita: Queen of Mars](http://www.standbyformindcontrol.com/2014/03/the-aelita-queen-of-mars-review-youve-been-waiting-90-years-to-read/), a 1924  Russian silent film  directed by Yakov Protazanov.

Nothing direct, but perhaps the different  environment  of mars  has  allowed females to develop a third breast as highlighted in the costume of the leading lady, Yuliya Solntseva

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that three breasts or just a really ugly woman in bad clothes

Comment: They appear to be halved kiwi fruits in the color illo.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

It is too in the Volume 1 (1962-1965) of « Little Annie Fanny » in the story from december 1964 called « Astronaut Annie » published originally in Playboy.

Answer (score 8):

There have been a number of multiply-breasted female characters seen in science-fiction and horror films. **Be warned, NSFW links below...**

*Four*-breasted characters are seen in;

- [Earth Girls are Easy](http://f3.to/mbap/images/film/earth3.jpg) (1989)
- [The Warrior and the Sorceress](http://f3.to/mbap/images/film/w&s3.jpg) (1984)

*Six*-breasted character are seen in

- [Necropolis](http://f3.to/mbap/images/film/necro.jpg) (1987)
- [Star Wars : Return of the Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Askajian) (1984)

---

<s>However, he first appearance of a ***three***-breasted character seems to be [Star Trek 5: The Final Frontier](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098382/) from 1989, released over a year before Total Recall.</s>

A cat-like alien woman with [three breasts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN69T.jpg) is seen in the cantina scene on Nimbus III.

---

<s>There's an even earlier match for a three-breasted character in the Sci-horror film "[Vicious Lips](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0163375/)" from 1986.</s>

A band finally gets the opportunity for that breakthrough gig if they can make it to an "in" club on another planet. They encounter a variety of [strange aliens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8a4Ki.png)....

**UPDATE**

I've found an even earlier match in the Sci-smut thriller [Galaxina](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLn3y4GMCBA) from 1980.

Our (ahem) heroes visit an alien brothel where they encounter many attractive alien females:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you can speak Italian this is from the '60s:

http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pupazza_frascatana

> La leggenda legata alla pupazza vuole che rappresenti una mammana, una balia che teneva a custodia i bambini delle donne impegnate nella vendemmia. Questa mammana era in grado di ammansire anche i bambini più agitati e capricciosi: a differenza delle sue colleghe, infatti, li imboniva allattandoli ad un seno finto con del buon vino di Frascati. Così, il dolce raffigura una donna con tre seni, due per il latte e uno per il vino.
>
> La leggenda, nata negli anni sessanta, oltre a legarsi goliardicamente alla viticoltura, una delle maggiori realtà produttive frascatane, si è diffusa in pochi anni come patrimonio iconografico locale. Sul territorio italiano si producono altri dolci detti pupazze, ma la pupazza frascatana è l'unica pupazza a rappresentare la figura femminile con tre seni."

This describes a mythical midwife who uses he three breasts, of which dispense milk and one of which dispenses wine, to soothe children.

Comment: I'm not sure whether a cookie counts as "fictional".