# Cover art on Lafferty's collection Nine Hundred Grandmothers

Tags: inspiration, art, lafferty

A [three-breasted woman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17770/who-first-implemented-the-three-breasted-character) is depicted on the cover, by artists [Leo and Diane Dillon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leo_and_Diane_Dillon), of the 1970 first edition of the [R. A. Lafferty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R._A._Lafferty) collection [*Nine Hundred Grandmothers*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?24318). Was this cover inspired by a particular story in the collection? Which one and how?

[image]

Most of the stories in this collection are freely available at sites like the Internet Archive, Project Gutenberg, etc.:

- [Nine Hundred Grandmothers](https://archive.org/details/1966-02_IF/page/n69/mode/2up)
- Land of the Great Horses
- [Ginny Wrapped in the Sun](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17Qr5AveR0hx5W8IF8AsFju9WtS2CRzmc/view)
- [The Six Fingers of Time](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/31663)
- Frog on the Mountain
- [All the People](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/51603)
- [Primary Education of the Camiroi](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v25n02_1966-12_modified/page/n149/mode/2up)
- [Slow Tuesday Night](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v23n04_1965-04/page/n129/mode/2up)
- [Snuffles](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v19n02_1960-12/page/n43/mode/2up)
- [Thus We Frustrate Charlemagne](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v25n03_1967-02/page/n125/mode/2up)
- [Name of the Snake](https://archive.org/details/Worlds_of_Tomorrow_v02n01_1964-04/page/n103/mode/2up)
- [Narrow Valley](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v031n03_1966-09_PDF/page/n75/mode/2up)
- [Polity and Custom of the Camiroi](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v25n05_1967-06_modified/page/n19/mode/2up)
- [In Our Block](https://archive.org/details/1965-07_IF/page/n69/mode/2up)
- [Hog-Belly Honey](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v029n03_1965-09_PDF/page/n93/mode/2up)
- [Seven-Day Terror](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/61128)
- The Hole on the Corner
- [What's the Name of That Town?](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v23n01_1964-10/page/n123/mode/2up)
- [Through Other Eyes](https://archive.org/details/Future_Science_Fiction_47_1960-02/page/n67/mode/2up)
- One at a Time
- [Guesting Time](https://archive.org/details/1965-05_IF/page/n45/mode/2up)

Comment: No _obvious_ references, so I'm going through the stories.  So far the closest in *feel* to the cover is "Through Other Eyes," but the woman in the story has the standard shape (unless it's unworthy of comment).

Comment: The woman need not necessarily have three breasts. The middle circle of the harness could be between them.

Comment: I suspect this is Questing Time, in specific the scene with all the people sitting on top of each other on the bench "*In that particular place, a talkative Skandia lady sat on the bench itself. On her lap sat a sturdy Skandia man reading the Sporting News and smoking a pipe. On him sat a younger Skandia woman. On this younger woman sat Truman Trux, and on him sat a dark Skandia girl who was filing her fingernails and humming a tune. On her in tum sat an elderly Skandia man. As crowded as things had become, one could not expect a seat of one's own*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the most literal terms, there is no three-breasted woman in any of the stories.  If there is any relationship between the cover and the stories in the collection, it must be allegorical.

For the main figure, the stories have relatively few female main characters, and the only one described as beautiful is Valery Mok, one of the scientists at "the Institute," and she is not described as unusual in appearance.  She also appears in several stories, so perhaps this figure is she.

In general feeling, the bright saturated colours and surreal appearance of the surrounding scene makes me think of "Through Other Eyes" wherein one of the male scientists invents a device that directly translates one person's sensorium onto another. He learns, for example, how the mathematician sees everything in terms of its mathematical expressions and relationships, how his mentor sees everything in perceptive and generous detail, and how another man is largely oblivious to much that is around him.

But when he tries on Valery Mok's sensorium it almost drives him crazy; there is too much colour everywhere, too many scents - even to different trees smelling differently, too much movement, too much detail.  She sees even the grass as mass of individual living, moving, vivid green stalks.  I get some of the feeling of that from the image.

As to particular elements of the image, the mask is probably a reference to Epikt's appearance towards the end of "Thus We Frustrate Charlemagne":

> the ghost Epikt, a kachenko mask with a speaking tube.

The black wings and the green-face toad creature are probably Shasos and Bater-Jeno from "Frog on the Mountain."  The horse may be a reference to "Land of Great Horses" though horses play only a minor role.